# .rake files and text editors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, faker

I'm trying to follow a Ruby on Rails tutorial by Michael hartl and he creates a sample_data.rake file for the Faker gem to create sample data and users. The problem is that this file doesn't show in the directory of files when I open the application in TextWrangler, and then when I force it open using TextWrangler, the text on the file is all black whereas normally programming language on a TextWrangler file will be different colors.

Is there something special about files ending .rake?

I'm such a lost newbie that I don't even really know if the functions it's running are working, so I'm a bit worried that I might be doing something wrong...

Answer (score 0):

You can tell your editor to treat `.rake` files as regular Ruby files. There is nothing special about rakefiles. The only reason the extension is different is to indicate that it should be run with the `rake`-command, not as plain ruby.

I don't know how to do that in TextWrangler, but there should be an option to set the file type.